# Positioning a div just before the footer of my page

Tags: html, css, sass

Attaching a page layout to explain my requirements better.
[image: Page layout]

1. Place the the text just before the footer section.
2. Some time the footer may not be visible (may need scroll), in that case bring the text to the bottom of visible area.

I have tried many ways to achieve this.
Any pointers to solve this issue would be helpful.

Thanks,
Santhosh

Comment: _"I have tried many ways to achieve this."_ Please post a [mcve] showing us exactly that so we don't waste your time and ours reproducing what you've done

Comment: Can you please include the code you currently have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use flexbox to achieve this

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.content {
  /* occupy all height */
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  /* nested flex container */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.bottom-text {
  /* Move to the bottom */
  /* This works because this is flex item */
  margin-top: auto;
}

/* styles just for demo */
body {
  text-align: center;
}

header {
  background-color: tomato;
}

.content {
  background-color: lightsteelblue;
}

.bottom-text {
  background-color: moccasin;
}

footer {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<header>Page header</header>
<section class="content">
  Page content
  <div class="bottom-text">Place a text just before footer</div>
</section>
<footer>Page footer</footer>
```

For showing `bottom-text` when `footer` is not visible we'll use Javascript:

```js
// Checks if element is visible on screen
function checkVisible(element) {
  var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  var viewHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight);
  return !(rect.bottom < 0 || rect.top - viewHeight >= 0);
}

var footer = document.querySelector("footer");
var bottomText = document.querySelector(".bottom-text");
var bottomTextFixedClassName = "bottom-text--fixed";

// Sets element position as fixed
// when footer is not visible on screen
function setFixedButtonText() {
  if (checkVisible(footer))
    bottomText.classList.remove(bottomTextFixedClassName);
  else
    bottomText.classList.add(bottomTextFixedClassName);
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", setFixedButtonText);

setFixedButtonText();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.content {
  /* occupy all height by flex-grow: 1 */
  /* Don't shrink using flex-shrink: 0 */
  /* Setting flex-basis to 1500px to emulate long content */
  /* Replace 1500px with auto in production code */
  flex: 1 0 1500px;
  /* nested flex container */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.bottom-text {
  /* Move to the bottom */
  /* This works because this is flex item */
  margin-top: auto;
}

.bottom-text--fixed {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

/* styles just for demo */
body {
  text-align: center;
}

header {
  background-color: tomato;
}

.content {
  background-color: lightsteelblue;
}

.bottom-text {
  background-color: moccasin;
}

footer {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<header>Page header</header>
<section class="content">
  Page content
  <div class="bottom-text">Place a text just before footer</div>
</section>
<footer>Page footer</footer>
```

If you need IE suppost you can use change `min-height: 100vh;` to `height: 100vh;`. This is workaround for IE's `min-height` bug for flex with `flex-direction: column;`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to handle this *"Some time the footer may not be visible (may need scroll), in that case bring the text to the bottom of visible area."*

Comment: is there a way to achieve this, I'm working on a react application which is created by a different team, some time back

Comment: @kallada Added scrolling behaviour (showing bottom text at screen bottom) using Javascript (cc @MichaelCoker)